# Как узнать на PHP есть ли у изображения альфа-канал

Tags: php

**Есть задача:** Загружать только прозрачные изображения

Как узнать на PHP есть ли у изображения альфа-канал, если нет, то блокировать дальнейшую обработку?

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен быть осмысленным

Comment: Использовать соответствуещие библиотеки zlib, png, jpeg

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("image.png");
$hasTransparency = $image->getImageAlphaChannel(); 
// will retuln 0 or 1 depends on image has or not transparency
```

**upd:**
Данное расширение (`ImageMagick`) может быть не установлено по-умолчанию если, например, локальный сервер собирался руками. На хостах почти всегда включёно, либо всегда можно включить в соответствующих настройках.

За итайте ImageMagick [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php)

Comment: Imagik таки не везде имеется.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил ответ.